# Xam.Plugin.Media wont work on Huawei devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to capture a photo but the camera won't open on my device. Huawei P9 with the latest version of Android. I am also using the latest version of the package. The package is working on my other phone but not on my Huawei phone.

```
var cafNo = entCafNo.Text;

        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "Ok");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = false,
                    Name = cafNo + "_IMG_01.png",
                    CompressionQuality = 80,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                }
            );

            entPhoto1Url.Text = file.Path;

            if (entPhoto1Url.Text != null)
            {
                btnCamera1.IsEnabled = false;
                btnCamera1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#27ae60");
                photovideovalidator.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Requesting runtime permissions for the camera?

Comment: @SushiHangover no the code works fine in my lg or samsung device in my huawei device its not working i dont know why

Comment: What are the API levels of the various devices?

Comment: @SushiHangover how can i know if this code is executed? ** await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();**

Comment: @SushiHangover all my devices are above api 27

Comment: @SushiHangover or how can I know if the camera is being executed?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to that line of code and debug it

Comment: @SushiHangover is there a way to notify a user if the camera is not initializing?

Comment: I do not think it is a device issue rather I would suggest you check on other devices with Android 9 and see if the same works or not also i would ask you check runtime permissions

Comment: @G.hakim I have checked its working in my other devices except my huawei p9 I also checked the runtime permissions

Comment: @G.hakim what can you suggest in my code?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your code .About android uerpermissions you can access https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/.It fit more device.

Comment: What android  API version do your other devices have ?